# Spring Boot API not starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a basic API to send sudoku puzzles and I am having trouble running the API. This is my first time trying to use Spring on my own and I followed the same steps as I did when I did the tutorial but it keeps crashing.

Here are the logs.

```
2023-05-04T12:34:40.727-04:00  INFO 21276 --- [           main] com.sudoku.SudokuApplication             : Starting SudokuApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 21276 (C:\Users\olive\Downloads\sudokuApi\demo\target\classes started by olive in C:\Users\olive\Downloads\sudokuApi\demo)
2023-05-04T12:34:40.734-04:00  INFO 21276 --- [           main] com.sudoku.SudokuApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-04T12:34:42.424-04:00  INFO 21276 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-04T12:34:42.424-04:00  INFO 21276 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-05-04T12:34:42.546-04:00  INFO 21276 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-04T12:34:42.658-04:00 ERROR 21276 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa
2023-05-04T12:34:42.666-04:00  INFO 21276 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-05-04T12:34:42.719-04:00 ERROR 21276 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

My application properties are below, I changed the username and password but I know for sure I have the right ones.

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sudoku
spring.datasource.username=CHANGED
spring.datasource.password=CHANGED

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Sudoku</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am not really sure how to read these kind of error codes so I copy pasted them and tried to find anything but nothing seems to work.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: mvn clean install should fix this

Comment: where do I run that?

Answer (score 0):

from your log "Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa"

looks like you don't have driver jar on your classpath

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the Postgres JDBC driver in your Maven pom.xml.  I'd recommend adding it unless I missed it:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I went back and saw that you have the driver, but there's no version.  I'm not sure why you made the scope runtime.  I'd change that.  Make sure you see the JAR in the package after you create it.

Comment: A scope of `runtime` should be OK for a JDBC driver - which should be loaded by SPI and is not needed for compilation. Also, for Spring Boot 3.0.6, that will cause `postgresql-42.5.4.jar` to be downloaded automatically - no explicit version needed. But this is a strange error, nonetheless (to me anyway).